# Need a method for link expiry in ruby after 2 days at 12:00 am on third day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Need to know the method to make a link expiry after 2 days at 12.00 am after registering

```
key = PaymentUrlKey.generate(booking.id, DateTime.now + 50.hours, "trek_fee")
```

using this is not helping also used

```
key = PaymentUrlKey.generate(booking.id, DateTime.now + 2.days, "trek_fee")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like

```
key = PaymentUrlKey.generate(booking.id, DateTime.now.beginning_of_day + 2.days, "trek_fee")
```